# Why isn't Putin excommunicated by the orthodox church?

Tags: russian-federation, religion

I wonder: Why isn't Putin excommunicated by the orthodox church?

It seems he likes to show up as Christian in church for political reasons, but what he does is not Christian at all.

Or does the orthodox church benefit from this symbiosis?

Comment: As this stands, this is an unanswerable question that requires knowing the internal thoughts of Orthodox Church officials, since presumably there are no public statements on this matter. However, if you want to change this to ask about the relationship between the Russian Orthodox Church and Putin, that would be a good question.

Comment: “It seems he likes to show up as Christian in church for political reasons, but what he does is not Christian at all.” That can be said of many politicians and many faiths.

Comment: Firstly, the followers of the *Russian Orthodox Church* are mostly Russians. Moreover, an important feature of Orthodox Christianity is that, unlike in Catholicism, the top church official  takes orders from the head of the state and not the other way round - therefore excommunicating Kings/Tsars was never an option, and not likely to happen now, even though Russia is a secular state and Putin has no authority over the Church.

Comment: @HHuang Indeed. One could have asked why George W. Bush wasn't excommunicated from his church for the 2003 invasion of Iraq, or similarly with the leaders of various countries intervening in the Kosovo War, etc, etc, and they would all be similarly unanswerable.

Comment: My opinion is that the orthodox church is just lacking good leaders. Its a observation that can be made all over the world through all christian denominations. They are opportunistic, stick to their position and lack the ability to estimate the current situation. The former russian Patriarch Alexius has once called Stalin "bogom danyi" , or "sended from God", a interpretation that could not been more wrong...  So, they continue with Putin the same way... Sad, but "history repeats itself" ...

Comment: @HHuang I think Bush did not show that much in church or with the pope in public news than Putin did or does. Also in the USA there is a much greater variety of religions, so by "just being roman catholic" you reach probably less people than being orthodox in Russia. And bush never had an appearance side-by-side with the pope (like Putin had with the patriarch). But I agree that *both* did misuse religion for their own purposes.

Comment: @U. Windl Just as a notice, Bush is not catholic, but evanglicane.

Comment: @convert Forgive a German, where the situation is much more simple (there are basically just two types of Christian churches); In the USA it's quite easy to visit the wrong church by mistake. Probably we can agree that if there's only one good, it doesn't make a big difference in the end (good'll be good, and bad'll be bad).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Russian Orthodox church recognizes quite a few military leaders as *saints*: notably, [Alexander Nevsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Nevsky) and [Theodor Ushakov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fyodor_Ushakov).

So, the dogmatic basis is not immediately apparent.

Having said that, Russian Orthodox church is basically an arm of Russian Federation state. Can't imagine them showing that level of disloyalty while Putin is still in power.

Comment: Maybe Russian orthodox church follows what I've heard about the orthodox church in Cyprus: "They are allowed to keep their properties if the keep out of politics" (Probably meaning not to comment in some negative way). Or maybe even most simply: "Money rules".

Comment: On "while Putin is still in power": So that seems to support my opinion that the church will benefit from Putin ("Never bite the hand that is feeding you"), and those benefits seem more important than actual religious belief.

Comment: Render unto Caesar the things that are Caesar's, and unto God the things that are God's.

Comment: I recently read a book explaining the relations between (dominant) church and state in various parts of the world. The chapter about Russia described the relation as *a symphony*. In other words, what this answer says.